# Session Value not set in ror devise form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

i had three ror devise forms...so i thought of adding after_sign_up_path_for .its working perfectly but the problem i am having is one of the forms using session hascode..when its redirected it shows hashcode is not set...

i tried lot of thins but its working when i add devise_for :users alone in routes.rb the session code is set but if i add this line ,session is not set but all three forms are redirecting correctly..

devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}

i am not sure what is causing the problem..please anybody help...

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)

     if resource.planner_type == "planner" 
      '/path1/invited_new'
      elsif resource.planner_type == "bride"
      '/path2/invited_new'
      else
        '/path3/invited_new'

      end
  end

end
```

Comment: which session u r talking about ..please explain what you want to do exactly..?\

Comment: Actually the problem what i am having is when i add devise_for :users in routes.rb the session value is set and the form values are saved but when i add devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"} in routes.rb the form is showing values not set and not saving to db...what is causing the problem?any idea? i wrote RegistrationsController to overide the sign up method and added devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"} ..its causing the problem

Comment: ok means your values are not being saved into database i think you are passing more values than just only email and password ..for this you have to allow them to pass to controller and getting save..you can confirure session controller by creating a filter in application controller checkout this link>>https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

Comment: values are saving...if i use devise_for :users the form is saving but if i replace with it by devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}...the form is not working..i dont what is going wrong..form is working perfectly..there is problem when i add registeration controlller in devise_for:users..

Comment: what is exact error you are getting..?

Comment: i am not getting error..my form is not saving when i add devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}..the form shows invalid type after i add this..If i remove the line its working..dont know what is causing the problem?